# I can't connect (NestJS app) to db which runs inside docker container with not root user

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

My docker compose file seems as below:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: cleaner-db
    restart: always    
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:      
      - ./volumes/mysql-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

My init.sh inside of docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:

```
#!/bin/bash

CLEANER_DBNAME="cleaner"
CLEANER_USERNAME="cleaner"
CLEANER_PASSWDDB="secret"
ROOT_PASSWD="example"

mysql -uroot -p${ROOT_PASSWD} -e "CREATE DATABASE ${CLEANER_DBNAME} /*\!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;"
mysql -uroot -p${ROOT_PASSWD} -e "CREATE USER ${CLEANER_USERNAME}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '${CLEANER_PASSWDDB}';"
mysql -uroot -p${ROOT_PASSWD} -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${CLEANER_DBNAME}.* TO '${CLEANER_USERNAME}'@'localhost';"
mysql -uroot -p${ROOT_PASSWD} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

My app.module.ts in NestJS. I use latest version of that:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'cleaner',
      password: 'secret',
      database: 'cleaner',
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: false,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I can connect via 'docker exec it', but NestJs prints the error: `Error: Access denied for user 'cleaner'@'192.168.0.1' (using password: YES)`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And the best practice is to use the root user for such things.
You can write a `*.sql` script and copy it to a special path in your mysql dockerfile (or docker-compose.yaml in my case)

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: your_username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userpassword
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

The name of my file was `init.sql` and the path `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` is a special path (read more about it in the mysql docker docu.

The sql file looks like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

`your_username` is the user you created in the docker-compose file. But you can do it in the sql file, too

```
CREATE USER 'your_username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'userpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

#### Important

The better way to go is: Use the root user to create databases. If you set a normal user the `superuser` level, the user can delete, create databases and so on. It's a big security way!